# TableViewCell disappears when push UINavigationController in UITabBarController's More tableview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I add 6 navigation controllers to UITabBarController's viewControllers. As normal, a More tab is created to list the last two. The problem is: after I select a table cell in the More table view, that cell's content fade out and disappear before the view controller push in. And then, after I back to the More table view by click the Back button, that cell's content show again. I guess the reason is More table view in its own navigation controller, and it push another navigation controller (created by me). I don't want to remove my navigation controller because I want to allow user rearrange tabs using the UITabBarController's Edit function. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Create instances of your 6 navigation controllers in AppDelegate and retain them. And release in dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. In my case I accidentally assigned the `tabBarItem` to the VC inside the navigation controller. When I instead initialized the `tabBarItem` on the navigation controller, the flickering / disappearing stopped.

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
// this has to be navigation.tabBarItem (not viewController.tabBarItem)
[navigation.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fancy.png"] 
                                          tag:42];
```

Initializing the tabBarItem on the viewController still showed the icon which made it harder to discover. I'm also not very sure (actually I think it's bad) about the way I initialize the tabBarItem (without alloc). But I had troubles with disappearing icons etc and hey, it works ;-)